# How to collect the number "20" from the string "TimeInterval 20" in c++?

Tags: c++, windows

I want to know how can we get the string 20 from the string "TimeInterval 20".

I know that using the below code i can get the string "TimeInterval" storing at cGetMinuteInterval.

```
UINT iCount = strcspn("TimeInterval 20"," ");
strncpy_s(cGetMinuteInterval,MAXCHARSIZE,"TimeInterval 20",iCount);
```

But what if i want the string 20 from the string "TimeInterval 20" & storing at cGetMinuteInterval.

Thanks & regards,
Abhineet

Comment: `"TimeInterval 20"[13];` In other words, you need to define the criteria for finding "20", and then program it.

Comment: @Abhineet da ty zhe poehavshiy

Answer (score 4):

As you are using C++, consider using `std::string` class and the `substr` function

Comment: Actually i am reading the file and the file data is stored at cReadConfigData variable. In this variable the value will be "TimeInterval 20".

Comment: @Abhineet I am not sure what you are saying. You can make a std::string from a char array, then use the substr function to locate, then extract the string portion you want

Answer (score 1):

Next snippet will put 20 in cGetMinuteInterval, this seems easiest in C++.  What you need next is some input checks to verify that your input (format, values,...) is as expected.

```
std::istringstream iss("TimeInterval 20");
std::string varName;
std::string cGetMinuteInterval;
iss >> varName >> cGetMinuteInterval;
std::cout << cGetMinuteInterval << "\n";
```

And if you want cGetMinuteInterval as integer, just change the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this.

```
string str = "TimeInterval 20" ;
int position = str.find("20") ;
cout << str.substr(position) ;
```

I think this is what you are trying to say?